# Laravel Routes Artisan

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

When I run artisan routes in laravel 4

```
auth/login/{v1}/{v2}/{v3}/{v4}/{v5}
```

Is this normal or is there something wrong. My routes work just wondering if there might be a bug or something. Below are my routes for auth. I'm using restful routes for auth.

```
Route::controller('auth','AuthController');

Route::get('AuthController/login', array('as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'AuthController@login'));
Route::get('auth/logout', array('as' => 'logout', 'uses' => 'auth@logout'));
Route::post('auth/login', array('uses' => 'auth@login'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected. When you register controllers with `Route::controller()` the controller inspector [adds the URI wildcards](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controllers/Inspector.php#L135). Consider the following example:

```php
Route::controller('user', 'UserController');
```

You might then have a method like this on your `UserController`:

```php
public function getProfile($username)
{
    $user = User::where('username', $username)->first();

    return View::make('profile')->with('user', $user); 
}
```

You could then hit that method by going to `localhost/yourapp/user/profile/jason`

In a nut shell it allows you to pass extra parameters to a method. To me this is a very old school way of doing it, as it looks nicer like `localhost/yourapp/user/jason/profile` and in this case you'd need to use a route to map to the controller method.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you 2 improvements:

**1 - keep a standard with URIs**

You don't need Route::controller in this case. In order to mantain all routes with the same structure I would do:

```
Route::group( array('prefix'=>'auth,function(){   //make all auth routes starting by auth
    Route::get('getLogin', array('as' => 'getLogin', 'uses' => 'AuthController@getLogin'));
    Route::get('getLogin', array('as' => 'logout', 'uses' => 'AuthController@logout'));
    Route::post('postLogin', array('as' => 'postLogin', 'uses' => 'AuthController@postLogin'));
});
```

It is not necessary to use group but if you app grows could be better. Without group code will be:

```
Route::get('auth/getLogin', array('as' => 'getLogin', 'uses' => 'AuthController@getLogin'));
Route::get('auth/getLogin', array('as' => 'logout', 'uses' => 'AuthController@logout'));
Route::post('auth/postLogin', array('as' => 'postLogin', 'uses' => 'AuthController@postLogin'));
```

**2 - Protect your post routes**

For every post and put request we've to prevent CSRF attacks like this:

```
Route::post('postLogin',array('before' => 'csrf','uses'=>AuthController@postLogin) );
```

Comment: Thank both of you for the help. I wanted to give both checks but only allows one and I don't want to stop using Route::controller to register restful routes.

Comment: in that case you could use ´Resources´ as follows:

    Route::resource('users','UsersControllers');

With this, you've the whole restful controller for users.